# Spring boot actuator optional parameter with default value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is there an alternative to this:

```
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "NA") in actuator 
@WriteOperation request body/query param?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should be able to make the request params optional using `org.springframework.lang.Nullable` annotation.